# Why does Rambam say the omer can be cut by day and on Shabas?

Tags: passover, rambam, machlokes, maseches-menachos, mincha-meal-offering

*Rambam* תמידין ומוספין chapter 7:

> מצותו להקצר בלילה בליל ששה עשר בין בחול בין בשבת. וכל הלילה כשר לקצירת העומר ואם קצרוהו ביום כשר
>
> The command of [the *omer*] is to be reaped at night, the night of the sixteenth [of *Nisan*], whether a weekday or *Shabas*. All night is suitable for the reaping of the *omer*; if they reaped it by day, it's valid.

*Lechem Mishne* asks the obvious<sup>[1]</sup> question (copy-pasted from the version at hebrewbooks.org):

> תימה דמשמע בפרק רבי ישמעאל (דף ע"ב) דמאן דאית ליה דקצירת העומר דוחה שבת אית ליה דנקצר ביום פסול דאי סלקא דעתיך כשר אמאי דוחה שבת כיון דעומר שנקצר שלא כמצותו כשר נקצריה מערב שבת דהא כ"ע אית להו כרבי עקיבא דאמר כל מלאכה שאפשר לעשותה מערב שבת אינה דוחה שבת וכן פסק רבינו ז"ל בפ' ראשון מהלכות קרבן פסח ואם כן רבינו ז"ל איך פסק דברים סותרים שדוחה שבת ואם נקצר ביום כשר וכן התוס' ז"ל בפ' ר' ישמעאל (דף ס"ו.) בדיבור זכר למקדש כו' פסקו דנקצר פסול והכריחו הדבר בראיות וחדא מינייהו משום דקי"ל דדחי שבת וכיון דדחי שבת ע"כ נקצר ביום פסול ולרבינו ז"ל שחילק הדברים לא ידעתי טעם וצ"ע

In sum, that it's valid if cut by day and that it's cut on *Shabas* are incompatible views. What, if any, answers exist to this question?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> That is, obvious to someone who has just studied *M'nachos* 72.

Comment: It looks like most of the commentaries on the sidebar of the [Hebrewbooks Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=8614) address this issue, and multiple answers are proposed.

Comment: @Fred, oh, thanks. I actually saw the _LM_  in a classical-edition _Rambam_, using the site only for the copy-paste, so didn't check the other commentators there. (No one on the _daf_ has an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The footnotes for the Eliyahu Touger translation( at the chabad.org site), on [*Hilkhot Temidin u-Musafin* 7:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1013259/jewish/Chapter-7.htm#footnoteRef17a1013259), for "[i]f it was reaped during the day, it is acceptable"([fn 18](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1013259/jewish/Chapter-7.htm#footnote18a1013259)), say:

> *Menachot* 72a states that the Sages that maintain that it is acceptable to harvest the barley for the offering during the day do not accept the view that this barley may be harvested on the Sabbath. How then can the Rambam accept both rulings? Nevertheless, since the Jerusalem Talmud (*Rosh HaShanah* 1:8, *Megilah* 2:7) does not see the two as contradictory, it is possible for the Rambam to accept both rulings.